# How to bind a query on the datagridview in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I'm planning to create a program that would bind the search results into the datagridview in vb.net. For example, listing of students that has the same course in the datagridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shoudl help you

[Displaying data in a DataGrid in VB.NET](http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataGridSamp04232005050133AM/DataGridSamp.aspx)

and

[DataGridView.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx)